# How to project a circle onto an angled plane?

Tags: circles, conic-sections

I have cut a hole in my ceiling to fit an 8 inch diameter circular duct perpendicular to my floor so it goes straight up.  The ceiling is pitched at 15 degrees.  I want to draw the shape that this hole made in my ceiling so I can cut something to go around it.   How can I do this?

Comment: it's going to be an ellipse, minor axis will be equal to diameter of the duct, major axis will be diameter of the duct divided by $\cos 15°$

Comment: ok, so I have an ellipse with a major axis of 10.53 and a  minor axis of 8.   Is there some tool that I can use to print out this shape?

Comment: GeoGebra, easy and free (www.geogebra.org).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Drawing_ellipses. The pins-and-string method will be easiest for your application. Your major axis length looks wrong, though. The cosine of 15° is pretty close to 1 but the ratio you’ve got is about 3/4.